# Do i need to use mongoose.connect(mongoose://localhost) in every file where I need data of a collection from data-base

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have used mongoose to connect to DB in the main app.js

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/tracks')
```

I want to access the DB from a different file say side-file.js
what I usually do is connect again and change the collection to what I need

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/tracks')
```

There must be a simple way out of this, as a singleton

Comment: No! you don't ...

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
const mongooseClient= require('mongoose');

const DbConnection = () =>  {

    var db = null;

    const getDBConnection = async () => {
        try {
            let url = 'Add MongoDB URL';
            let db = await mongooseClient.connect(url, {useNewUrlParser:true, useUnifiedTopology:true});
            return db
        } catch (e) {
            return e;
        }
    }

   const getInstance = async () => {
        try {
            if (db != null) {
                console.log(" db connection is already alive");
                return db;
            } else {
                console.log('getting new connection');
                db = await getDBConnection();
                return db; 
            }
        } catch (e) {
            return e;
        }
    }

    return getInstance
 
}


module.exports = DbConnection();
```

In any module you can use it like, the above function will only allow one instance for the connection.

```
const dbConnection = require('./path to file');

async function save() {

  try {
    const db = dbConnection();
    const result = await db.save(...);
    console.log(result);
  }
  catch (e) {
     console.log(`Error in saving : ${e}`)
  }
  
}
```

Generally, you connection to the database which contains different collection and you can save update data based on mongoose schema you have created. You don't need to change the URL for every collections.